# Fail when I try to send JSON Object to server

Tags: java, android

I have a JsonObject and i want send it to a server from my Android client.

I am following some tutorials and codes but server alway receives a post request empty.

This is my code:

```
public String POST(String url, JSONObject object) {

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";

    try {

        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String json = "";

        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = object.toString();

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the
        // content
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if (inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

        Log.i("telo","respuesta: "+result);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    // 11. return result
    return result;
}

private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
        throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}
```

What am i doing wrong? some help

thanks

Comment: your json is empty!!!

Comment: why? do you refer to my json string no?

Comment: i comrpobe my json string after assign and not is empty

Comment: why do you use `convertInputStreamToString` when httpclient comes with responseHandler and entityutils ?

Comment: umm this code is from tutorial, but now I am thinking you are rigth, but it is not the problem, because the answer that i receive is correct

Comment: oh sorry, i missed that you were passing an object.

Comment: have you tried logging that json String and seeing what it looks like

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

// Request parameters and other properties.
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("object", object.toString()));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

//Execute and get the response.
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

if (entity != null) {
    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
    try {
        // do something useful with instream
    } finally {
        instream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: ummm HttpClients not recognise this class

Comment: Replace first line in above snippet with `HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();`.

Comment: thansk but the problems continues... :(

Comment: that seems strange.. have you checked to make sure that your api is expecting POST Json?  the problem may be on that side

Answer (score 0):

trye changing: ("Content-type", "application/json"); to ("Content-Type", "application/json");

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use .toJSONString() and not .toString()

Please try that :)

Comment: this option not appears me

Comment: this answer is wrong, because `toJSONString` is not a method of `JSONObject`, and moreover, the documentation for `JSONObject` states to use `toString`.

Comment: I use org.json.simple.JSONObject and it has that function! WHat library are you using?

Comment: default libaray in android org.json.JSONObject;

Comment: Please look at Example 4 in this reference doc. Its exactly what you are looking for. (Using toJSONString()) https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples

Comment: @user2855036: absolutely not. your example is about `JSONValue.toJSONString(Map<>)`. The OP is using `org.json`, not `org.json.simple`, as it is the default android library for JSON. See http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: @njzk2 I was saying I solved it that way! It is clear he is not using org.json.simple. It is my alternative, a library from google that makes just easier simple things.

Comment: Your answer should reflect the suggestion to use a different library, then. In its current form, it suggests to use a method that does not exist, and is not very usable.